# Prove $\gcd \left(\frac{a}{\gcd (a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd (a,b)}\right)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's define $\mathbb{N}^*$ first: $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} - \{0\}$

> Prove if $a$ & $b$ & $d$ $\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $gcd(a,b)=d$ and
>   $a=d\cdot k$ and $b=d\cdot n$ then $gcd(k,n)=1$.

In order to resolve it, I've done the following:

We have $a=d\cdot k$ and $b=d\cdot n$ so:
$$\frac{a}{k}=\frac{b}{n}$$

And we can easily show that if $\zeta \in \mathbb{N}^*$ then: $gcd(\zeta,\zeta)=\zeta$

Thus: $$gcd(a\cdot n, b \cdot k)=d$$

But can I directly do: $$\frac{gcd(a\cdot n, b \cdot k)}{gcd(a,b)=d}=\frac{d}{d} = 1$$
and the $a$, $b$ cancel out so I get the final result: $gcd(k,n)=1$ and why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the original problem. On the one hand, if you know your question to be true, then you can certainly use it. On the other hand, if you don't know that to be true, then you are assuming the answer to the original problem (which is not okay).

Comment: You have $\frac{a}{k} = d = \frac{b}{n}$, so $a\cdot n = b \cdot k = d\cdot k\cdot n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The last expression has a fault in the end. It's $a\cdot n = b \cdot k = d$ not $a\cdot n = b \cdot k = d\cdot k\cdot n$.

Comment: @mixedmath Well I know it's true but I have to prove that it is true without using induction.

Comment: @Adobe $a\cdot n = \frac{a}{k}\cdot k\cdot n$, and by assumption, $a = d\cdot k$, so $\frac{a}{k} = d$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah! Sorry... (tired) But how can I use that result to prove the content of the question?

Comment: Let $g = \gcd(k,n)$. What can you say about $d\cdot g$?

Comment: Hmm.. I have no idea... I'm locked at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $gcd(a,b)=d$. This leads to conclusion that $a=k \cdot d$ and $b = n \cdot d$

Now let $gcd(k,n) = m$, then we can write: $k = s \cdot m$ and $n = t \cdot m$. Substitute back we have: $a = s \cdot m \cdot d$ and $b = t \cdot m \cdot d$. Both $a$ and $b$ have $md$ asa factor, but we know that $gcd(a,b) = d$, so that implies $m=1$

Q.E.D.

Also another way is to use the following property of the function Greatest Common Divisor:

$$gcd(ma,mb) = m \cdot gcd(a,b) \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}; m \neq 0$$

Let $a = kd$ and $b=nd$. Then from assumtion we have:

$$gcd(a,b) = d$$
$$gcd(kd,nd) = d$$
$$gcd(k,n) \cdot d = d$$
$$gcd(k,n) = 1$$

Q.E.D.

To make it clear the Greatest Common Divisor is as I would like to call it "semi-multiplicative" function, i.e. it's multiplicative, but only under specific condition. For example, this will hold:

$$gcd(ma,b) = gcd(m,b) \cdot gcd(a,b)$$

if $gcd(m,a) = 1$

So your calculation is wrong because it true that:

$$gcd(\frac ak, \frac bn) = d$$

But you multiply both sides with $nk$, that will change the value of The GCD, unless $(n,k) = (a,n) = (b,k) = 1$, but we can't make that restriction.

Also that division will never lead to an answe that $gcd(n,k)=1$. Because we can make the following factorization if $(a,n) = (b,k) = 1$

$$gcd(a \cdot n, b \cdot k) = (a,b) \cdot (a,k) \cdot (b,n) \cdot (n,k)$$

But obviouly we can't make that restriction. For counterxample take $a=12$ and $b=18$.This will provide $d=6$, $k=2$, $n=3$.

So in your example you'll have:

$$(a\cdot n, b \cdot k) = (36,36) = 36 \neq d = 6$$

Comment: The second way seems to be correct so why can't we divide as I tried?

Comment: @Adobe It was a little bit longer to write in the comments, so you can read my edited answer.

Comment: That's really helpful @Stefan4024 thank you!